# SQL Server Alias for connection name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If in a SQL Server stored procedure you have a `select` statement with a join to a table that is not in the current connection, you can do that like this.

```
Select a 
from Table1 t1
inner join on connection2.DataBase2.table2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a
```

I want to know if it is possible to set up an alias for my foreign connection, something like

```
Alias MyConnection = Connection2

Select a 
from Table1 t1
inner join on MyConnection.DataBase2.table2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a
```

This is because my foreign connection, `Connection2` in this example, occurs many times in my SQL Server stored procedure, and at some point the database, `Database2`, is moving to a new connection and I would rather just change one line than many.

I hope this is clear and thanks.

Bob

Comment: What do you mean by foreign connection? The way you have posted is that this is a different database. Is that what you mean? And is Database2 going to renamed or is it going to be moved to a new server? The answer is vastly different depending on the answers here.

Comment: Why not use a synonym for the table with scope "connection2.database2.table2"? This way you can have one script that'll drop and recreate synonyms based on "connection2" for each environment you have.

Comment: Are you expecting to do something like `MyConnection.DataBase2 as DB2` ??

Comment: I found out since I posted that synonyms is what I want. by foreign connection I just meant a database on a different server,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ~create~ a synonyn for a linked server (or another db in the same database-instance)

```
CREATE SYNONYM LinkedTableA
FOR
ServerName.DBName.dbo.TableA


SELECT * FROM LinkedTableA
```

See.

http://www.pressthered.com/sql_server_synonyms_and_linked_servers/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx

But the synonym needs to be created.  There are no "local scope" aliaseseseseses.. (aliai ?)